# BadImageFormatException and valid Win32

Tags: c#, winapi, console-application, badimageformatexception

I have a C# application that runs well on my work laptop. However, the same application cannot run on my home laptop, I get an error saying: `System.BadImageFormatException HResult=0x800700C1 Message=Could not load file or assembly 'xxx.dll' or one of its dependencies. is not a valid Win32 application. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x800700C1)`

Both are Windows 10, both Visual Studio 2017 and have also the same configurations. 
What might be the issue and solve it?

Comment: 32/64 bit mismatch

Comment: @DavidHeffernan ok, and how to solve it?

Comment: Make sure all the modules are the same bitness. Likely it will relate to the runtime library that one of your dependencies relies on. But that's a guess. We can only guess without more detail.

Comment: Enable the [Show loader snaps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/debugger/setting-and-clearing-system-wide-flags) option in [GFlags](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/debugger/gflags), and have it report the culprit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure 'xxx.dll' and **all of its dependencies** is the same as your OS architecture(x86/x64). Use dependency walker to find out the dependant modules.